# Decomposition of a matrix as direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I have a $4 \times $ matrix $M$ which I will write in terms of blocks as follows:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I know that $M$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ with two associate eigenvectors, say $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$. In addition, $M$ has two other eigenvectors $v_{3}$ and $v_{4}$ associated to two different eigenvalues. Is it possible to write $M$ as a direct sum of matrices:
$$M = M_{1}\oplus M_{2}$$
where $M_{1}$ is a linear map on the subspace generated by $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ and $M_{2}$ is a linear map on the subspace generated by $v_{3}$ and $v_{4}$? If so, is there a recipe to construct such direct sum explicitly?

*Note:* The matrix $M$ is assumed as a linear map on $\mathbb{C}^{4}$.

Comment: Yes: $M_1$ is just restriction of $M$ to the first subspace and $M_2$ is the restriction of $M$ to the second subspace.

Comment: @BenGrossmann is there a formula which allows me to explitly construct such matrices?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you mean by the *matrix* of $M_1$ in this context since $M_1$ is an operator on a subspace of $\Bbb C^4$ rather than an operator on $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I was thinking of decomposing $\mathbb{C}^{4} = \mathbb{C}^{2}\oplus \mathbb{C}^{2}$, so that $M \varphi = M_{1}\varphi_{1}\oplus M_{2}\varphi_{2}$.

Comment: Identifying the each subspace with $\Bbb C^2$ means choosing a basis of the subspace. If you use $v_1,v_2$ as a basis of the first and $v_3,v_4$ as a basis of the second, then taking the direct sum of the matrix of $M_1$ relative to the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ and the matrix $M_2$ relative to the basis $\{v_3,v_4\}$ gives you the matrix of $M$ relative to the basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$. That said, this really just amounts to diagonalizing $M$.

Comment: Ben, but if I know M, how can I construct $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$?

Comment: Is it enough to diagonalize M and take its block-diagonal matrices?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "constructing $M_1$ and $M_2$"